# WebStorm suggesting I flip if-else, what are the benefits of doing so?

Tags: node.js, if-statement, webstorm

I've seen this happen a few times in WebStorm. Here's an example of a time when it happens.  I have a module for logging messages sent to a chatbot and the responses.  The `log()` function looks like this:

```
log: function(senderID, type, event) {
    if (type === 1) {
        // Event
        logDate = datetime.parseUnixDBDate(event.timestamp);
        logTime = datetime.parseUnixTime(event.timestamp);
        logText = handleText(event.message.text);
        table = "interactions";
        columns = ["fbid", "date", "time", "event"];
        logType = "User input";
    } else {
        // Response
        logDate = datetime.getDBDate();
        logTime = datetime.getTime();
        logText = handleText(event);
        table = "interaction_responses";
        columns = ["fbid", "date", "time", "response"];
        logType = "Chatbot response";
    }
    values = [`'${senderID}'`, `'${logDate}'`, `'${logTime}'`, `'${logText}'`];
    logSQL = `INSERT INTO ${table} (${columns.toString()}) VALUES (${values.toString()})`;
    database.query(logSQL);
    console.log("%s '%s' logged at %s on %s.", logType, logText, logTime, logDate);
}
```

In WebStorm, I get a little light bulb next to the `if` statement, and if I click the warning it suggests that I should "Flip if-else".  If I do this, I then get the SAME warning suggesting I flip the if-else back.  Warning looks like this:

[image: WebStorm Warning Message]

Is there a reason why this is happening?  Should I flip my if-else statement?

Comment: I have no idea about Webstorm, but I know certain IDEs offer the option to switch things like this for you - it's not a warning, it's just a suggestion so you don't have to do the work yourself. Pycharm, for example, offers the ability to toggle between single- and double-qouted strings, in both directions. Neither is *right* but if you change your mind you don't have to do a bunch of tedious typing.

Comment: Maybe the light bulb isn't a warning, but "an idea"

Comment: Ok @CodyG., perhaps "idea" is a better word! ;-)

Comment: @MikeTheLiar thanks for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an "[intention action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/intention-actions.html)". There's no inherent benefit to doing it one way or the other, it's just a way for you to quickly restructure/refactor your code when the fancy strikes.

It appears to be a feature in all [Jetbrains IDEs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html).

You can see the entire list of intentions, their descriptions, and enable/disable them as you see fit in [Settings and Options](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/settings-preferences-dialog.html).